# Mongodb model to store user/item specific data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The case:
There are users in system, and there are static documents (like books) Each user may work with some documents and have specific state/settings (like current position/page in document, bookmarks/notes) for each of his docs.

What is a better way to store that user and document specific information in flat collection with two keys userId and documentId or collection that have _id equal to userId and nested array of subdocuments that have _id equal to documentId (in that scenario collection is also used for storing non-document specific user data)?

> 1st scenaroio: find({userId: ..., documentId:...})
>
> 2nd scenaroio: findBy({_id:...}), then find sub doc with _id equal to documentId

PROS of 1st scenario:

> 1) I believe quicker find and save operations.

CONS of 1st scenario:

> 1) greater amount of documents
>
> 2) no way to store some non-doc related user-specific data in collection

PROS of 2nd scenario:

> 1) better representation of data relations (subjective though)
>
> 2) makes possible to use the same collection to store some other non particular document related user data.

CONS of 2nd:

> 1) more difficult search and more difficult save operations (I'm using using Mongoose ODM and code would not be complex), and I think the operations is less speedy then in 1st scenario.

Some things to consider:

> 1) In general in read operations I would to select only one document specific data
>
> 2) I would need OFTEN to save one document specific data (for example periodical saving of position in document that user is working with).
>
> 3) User/document state may have some nested arrays (bookmarks, notes) that have to be changed (docs inserted/removed)

Taking this considerations I would say that 1st scenario  is more suitable for the task, but I would like to hear some pro opinions, whether two scenarios differ greatly.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't worry about write performance. Optimize for your queries.

Comment: @Esteban Araya Thanks, but What do you mean by "optimize queries"? And do you have any preference over 1st or 2nd scenario, which one would you go with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your actual access paths? Do you start with a user id, and the look for the documents the user reads? Or do you start with a document and search for the users, that read it?
Is the document object lightweight (just title and author and suchlike information) or is it heavyweight (includes the contents)?
If documents are heavyweight, I'd keep them in a separate collection and go for scenario 2.

Basically scenario 1 mimics a relational solution and scenario looks like an object model.

I believe object models describe the reality better and are more efficient.

So I'd go for scenario 2, unless you frequently search the readers for a book.

Comment: Document state is not heavy, common scenario I need to get one at a time (one doc state for a user). And I don't need to get users for a particular document often, at least it is definitely not a real-time scenario for an application. What I often need to do often is to save state of a particular document.